# NullPointerException when referencing ImageView Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to build an app that uses the device's camera, takes a picture in one `fragment`, and displays that picture in a separate `fragment`. My app uses a `DrawerLayout` and several `fragments`. In the main Activity `class` when I try to reference the `ImageView` I would like to edit within the `xml` file of one of my `fragments` I am met with a NPE:

```
ImageView imgTaken = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_imageView);
```

I have been encountering these types of exceptions too frequently; I think there is something about using `View` objects that I am not familiar with. If anybody has any useful insight on why exactly I may be repeatedly finding my code not working due to a NPE, please feel free to enlighten me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do u make sure that the layout file contain the post_imageView id?

Comment: @herokingsley yes, everything is there; that's why I'm confused that this wont work

Comment: Please post some more code and xml. The current information is not sufficient to answer.

Comment: If the ImageView is in one of your fragment layouts, and the fragment has not yet been added to the activity, then `findViewById` will return null because it the view is not in the view hierarchy yet. Where are you adding the fragment to the activity (or are you adding the fragment directly in the XML layout for the activity)?

Comment: do you have any id for your xml layout????           If have then reference it and call as by that reference your image view  eg   in your activity   nameofyourlayoutid   = mylayout; and reference as    ImageView imgTaken = (ImageView) mylayout.findViewById(R.id.post_imageView);

Comment: @Karakuri my app contains only two activities: an Login screen and a Navigation Drawer containing several fragments. After leaving the Login screen and calling the Nav Drawer, all fragments would be added, correct?